# Java Schedule twice a week

Tags: java, calendar, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I've been reading stackoverflow and I learnt that my threadpool scheduler can be put inside another scheduler to specify a calendar date in which to run for example a monday.  If I put the actual program inside a class I can then run 2 calendars and run on Monday and Friday.

How would I go about doing this? Could you give me an example of running a scheduler inside a calendar scheduler??

How does quartz scheduler triggers work??

Comment: Usually I don't advocate libraries, but have you seen Quartz Scheduler? AFAIK, it can schedule by [CRON](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example3.html) expressions. (Which includes "Every Monday and Friday")

Comment: OK I will look into Quartz scheduler

Comment: OK I looked at the API do I place the trigger inside the executorService and it will wait till the day of week is reached and then resume... like a very long thread.sleep

Comment: I haven't used it myself. I've just seen it being recommended from time to time.